# TCP sockets python timeout public IP address

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to communicate between a server and client using TCP sockets.

Server code:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('my-server-ipadress', 1999)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
 try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

Client code:

```
from socket import *

clientsocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

clientsocket.connect(("my-server-ip-address",1999))

recv = clientsocket.recv(1024)

print(recv)
```

It is working fine on a local connection. The problem I am facing is when I run the client code on my laptop (using my home wifi network)and try to communicate with the remote server, it is not able connect to the server. What could be the problem ? Any changes in the code required, or do I need to disable firewall on my laptop ?

The error I get is, error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

**EDIT:**
Changed server code to the following:

```
from socket import *

HOST = ''
PORT = 1999
serversocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((HOST,PORT))
serversocket.listen(5)
while True:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print ("Got client request from",address)
    clientsocket.send("Thank You for connecting")
    clientsocket.close()
```

But, still getting same error.
The server and client programs work well when I run both the client and server codes on my linux server. But when I run the client code on my laptop from an external network, it does not work.

Comment: disable the firewall on both the labtop and the server.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Disabling the firewall on the serve would not be a permanent solution. Any other way of doing it on the server ?

Comment: You need to accept the connection on your server. Look at socket.accept() (accept a connection, returning new socket and client address)

Comment: Thank you. will try. When I used www.google.com as the host and 80 as the port it worked fine.

Comment: @riotbit Pls see the updated server code above with accept(). Still getting the same error.

Comment: @bhuvan It is probably a typo that the server is bound to `8080` but the client is trying to connect to `1999` ? Try to use a tool like [nmap](http://nmap.org/) from the client to test the open/reachable ports on your server. This will help to narrow the scope of your issue.

Comment: The server and client programs work well when I run both the client and server codes on my linux server. But when I run the client code on my laptop from an external network, it does not work.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Sorry, I actually changed it to 1999 in both codes. It still doesnt work. The server and client programs work well when I run both the client and server codes on my linux server. With the server socket code runnign on my linux server, and when I run the client code on my laptop from an external network, it does not work

Comment: @bhuvan You should definitively investigate a network issue. `nmap` is really a great tool for that. Many others could help you from, `ping` to `wireshark`. For now, all we can say would be purely speculative...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux thank you. I scanned the server from my laptop and found out that there are only 3 TCP open ports available (80, 443,22). So, I should now make port 1999 also an open port, which would solve my issue I suppose ?

Comment: @bhuvan As you have narrowed your issue, may I suggest you to close this question and write _an other one_ focusing only on that point? (showing first the result of your scanning, mentioning the OS both of the server and client -- and finally the updated code both from the server and the client) That way, your issue will get the deserved attention (and I hope, detailed answers) ! Someone might even be able to point you to a duplicate question that solved the same kind of issue. Would be of a great help too...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux thank you. have posted the other question and would close this  question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the main problem is that the client is waiting for data, the `data = socket.recv(BUFSIZE)` is a blocking command and you are not sending data from the server, try to send something

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('my-server-ipadress', 1999)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
 try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            connection.send("hello")
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

more logic then coding
the client is waiting for data and the server too,
so in the bringing someone suppose to send data